# Can we create fulfillment service(end point) of google home without node.js?

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, google-home, fulfillment

I have created a web service in my application which does not support `nodejs` as an end point of `fulfillment`. 
I am getting `request header` correctly but the `JSON` data (request parameters) is garbage value.

My question is:-
Can we create `fulfillment` service(end point) of google home without `nodejs` ?

If yes, then what configurations I need to take care off ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely. All you need to do fulfillment is

- A public HTTPS server with a valid certificate.
- Something that listens on that server, can handle [JSON sent to it](https://developers.google.com/actions/build/json/dialogflow-webhook-json#dialogflow-request-body), and reply with [JSON in the expected format](https://developers.google.com/actions/build/json/dialogflow-webhook-json#dialogflow-response-body).

You can write this second one in any language you wish.

If your actual problem is that the JSON being sent to you seems wrong, then you should probably post the code you're using, what you're getting, and why you think it is incorrect.

Comment: Well the answer is:- YES, we can create fulfillment service(end point) of google home without nodejs. After doing some modifications in my application I received correct JSON format.